# what's the difference between a YouTube channel and content owner

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics

YouTube Analytics API Provides two types of Reports

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports

1.Channel Reports
2.Content Owner Reports.

Can any one expalin the differences between a YouTube channel and content owner?

Comment: Aren't they listed right next to the words?

Comment: they are listed, but i am looking to understand in easy way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Channels Reports:

> contain user activity metrics for a specified channel.

In other words, a Youtube Channel is your account.

The Content Owner Reports:

> aggregate metrics for all of the channels linked to a specified YouTube content owner. They can include user activity metrics as well as metrics related to revenue and ad performance.

In other words, the Content Owner is you as an individual. This report collects and puts together all the data from all the Youtube Channels linked to you. (this report focuses more on revenue and ad performance, as is stated)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, to some extent it is clear, need to dig more for clear understanding.

Comment: In short, YOU as a person are the Content Owner, and you could own content from multiple Youtube Channels. A Youtube Channel is just one area where you as a Content Owner can put your content.

Comment: yes, think so, Means if the videos uploaded by me are subscribed from other people / channels in youtube, then i am as a content owner owns videos from multiple youtube channels. am  i in right track. on the other way, youtube channel is my account where i upload my own videos to my account.

Comment: Correct, your channel is where you upload your videos on your account. It's also important to note from the "Content Owner Reports" section of the docs: "Note: Content owner reports are only accessible to YouTube content partners who participate in the YouTube Partner Program."

Comment: Thanks everything for your replies and explanations